# fetch data from database and update its with API's new data

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update, auto-update

We want to update database from API data, we have almost 100000 Records that all records are update day by day, i need to update with new data by using API.

Script Working Details
We are fetching $productId From store and from this $productId we will fetch updated data from API Script, after getting updated data we will update that updated data in to the store table.

is it possible that after update one data its automatic click on one button and its going for update for next $productId ?

```
<?php

// Mysql Connection //

$table_name= "store";

$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT productId FROM $table_name" );
while ( $rows =  $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
$pid = $rows['productId']; // Product code here
}

// API Script Here For - Getting Data from Api by fetching $pid code every, API Script is revert only single $pid details //

include "../extra/clusterdev.flipkart-api.php";
$flipkart = new \clusterdev\Flipkart("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "json");

$url = 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/product/json?id=' .$pid;

$details = $flipkart->call_url($url);

if(!$details){

    echo 'Error: Could not retrieve products list.';

    exit();
}

$details = json_decode($details, TRUE);
$mrp = $details['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['maximumRetailPrice']['amount'];
$newPrice = $details['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['sellingPrice']['amount'];
$newInStock = (int) $details['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['inStock'];
$discountPercentage = $details['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['discountPercentage'];

if ($newInStock == 1)
{ $newInStock= 'true'; } else { $newInStock = 'false'; }
echo $newInStock;
echo '<br />';
echo $newPrice;
echo '<br />';

// Mysql Connection //

$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT price,inStock FROM $table_name WHERE productId = '$pid' ") ;
while ( $rows =  $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
$price = $rows['price'];
$inStock = $rows['inStock'];
}

if ($newPrice != $price || $newInStock != $inStock)
  {
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE $table_name SET price='$newPrice', inStock='$newInStock' WHERE productId='$pid' ");

if($results){
    print 'Success! record updated'; 
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}
  }

// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: If you doing this for multiple `$pid`s this wont work.

Comment: So how what i need to change in my code @Alex

Comment: First of all you are defining `$table_name= "store";` 2 times @Pratik Soni

Comment: i made changes, can you suggest me what changes i need to do more @Alex

Comment: Do not provide login credentials in the questions. @Pratik Soni

Comment: @Alex i just made correction. but i don't have more knowledge of stackoverflow and php also.

Comment: So `$newPrice` and `$newInStock` will change for each of your product ID's ?

Comment: Yes. it will change on each product Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80389/discussion-between-alex-and-pratik-soni).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows :

```
$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT productId,price,inStock FROM $table_name ") ;
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $pid = $rows['productId'];
    $price = $rows['price'];
    $inStock = $rows['inStock'];

    if ($newPrice != $price || $newInStock != $inStock){
        $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE $table_name SET price='$newPrice', inStock='$newInStock' WHERE productId='$pid' ");
        if($results){
            print 'Success! record updated'; 
        }else{
            print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just use code but its update only single productid details.